# Get mandatory arguments for getopts

Tags: bash, arguments, getopts

I want to make some flags and their corresponding arguments as mandatory in `getopts`. The way I am doing so is by checking if the argument was passed or not for the mandatory flag, like so (flag for -i and it's argument should be mandatory):

In test.sh:

```
while getopts "i:n:d:r:p:s:l:" opt; do
    case $opt in
    i) thefile=$OPTARG;;
    n) size=$OPTARG;;
    d) dmax=$OPTARG;;
    r) rmsd=$OPTARG;;
    p) penalty=$OPTARG;;
    s) sampling=$OPTARG;;
    l) log=$OPTARG;;
    h) printf "Usage: `basename $0` options -i [input_file.txt]\n \
        -i input file\n \
        -n size\n  \
        -d dist\n \
        -r rflag\n \
        -p pflag \n \
        -l 0/1 for generating log file (optional, default=1)\n \
        -h for help \n";;
    \? ) echo "Unknown option: -$OPTARG" >&2; exit 1;;
    :  ) echo "Missing option argument for -$OPTARG" >&2; exit 1;;
    *  ) echo "Unimplemented option: -$OPTARG" >&2; exit 1;;
 esac
done

if [ "s" == "s$thefile" ]
then
    echo "-i must be included with a specified file" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

The problem is that one can run the script as so:
`./test.sh -i -n 4` and it still runs with the value of `-i` as "-n". How can I make this foolproof, so the flag is always used and used with a valid string argument for it?

Comment: Well `getopts` does what you tell it to do. You want an argument with the `-i` option so `getopts` gives it to you. Even if the next argument is `-n`. The thing is, files can start with `-`, so `-n` is a valid filename.

Comment: Exactly as the above comment from PesaThe, you are left only with a way to see if the option argument does not start with a `-` and throw a message saying no option passed (well if that's what you are after)

Comment: I see. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I would write: `if [[ -n $theFile && -f $theFile && -r $theFile ]]` to test that the argument is non-empty, a file, and readable.

Comment: @glennjackman Nice! Thanks for the tip!